# how to print out x amount of results per line

Tags: c++, for-loop

For this code I created that outputs the ASCII characters corresponding to `int`s, I need to print out 16 ASCIIs per line. How would I go about doing so? I'm not sure how to approach these? Do I create another `for` loop inside?

```
int main()
{
    int x = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i <= 127; i++)
    {
        int x = i;
        char y = (char) x;
        cout << y;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Or should I put the `cout` outside with 16 separate lines? I am trying to print 17 ASCIIs starting from 1 in a row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use another variable that counts up along with i.  When it reaches 16, reset it and print a new line. Repeat until the loop terminates.

i.e.(*I may be off by one here, I didn't think about it too deeply*)

```
for (int i=0, j=1; i<=127; i++,j++)
{
    int x = i;
    char y = (char) x;
    cout << y;

    if (j == 16) {
        j = 0;
        cout << '\n';
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you could just check `if (i % 16 == 0)`

Comment: Would that be like a forloop inside it?

Comment: @mystycs: No, it would just be an additional variable counting up adjacent to i, once per loop iterator.

Comment: I dont think im sure how to approach that. Is there a place you can direct me to on studying this?

Comment: I got it! I get it now what you do is tell if to go 16 times then set it to 0 and once it hits 16 again bam! it breaks line!

Answer (score 1):

<s>Yes, you need a second loop inside the first.</s> (I misunderstood what is being requested.)

You also need to clean up the code.  The first `x` is unused; the second `x` isn't needed since you could perfectly well use `char y = (char)i;` (and the cast is optional).  You should normally use a loop `for (int i = 0; i < 128; i++)` with a `<` condition rather than `<=`.

You will also need to generate a newline somewhere (`cout << endl;` or `cout << '\n';`).  Will you be needing to deal with control characters such as `'\n'` and `'\f'`?

Finally, I'm not sure that 'asciis' is a term I've seen before; the normal term would be 'ASCII characters'.

Comment: Ah i see i declared the x as 0 but i already declared it within the loop

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    for(int i = 0, j = 0; i < 128; ++i, ++j)
    {
        if(j == 16)
        {
            j = 0;
            std::cout << std::endl;
        }

        std::cout << static_cast<char>(i);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Every iteration, `j` increases by `1`; after `16` iterations, `j` is reset to 0, and a newline is printed.

---

Alternatively, as @Sujoy points out, you could use:

```
if((i % 16) == 0)
    std::cout << std::endl;
```

But this introduces the problem of printing an extra newline character at the beginning of the output.

Comment: Did you forget to output the new line character?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need another variable to track it. `i` is already an int.

so `if i modulo 16 equals 0 then print a newline`
else print `(char)i`

**EDIT:**

Note, using variables like `i` is ok for simple iteration but its always good practice to name them better.
So think about how changing `i` to `ascii` in your program improves the readability. It instantly makes it even more clear what is it that you are trying to do here.

Comment: Oh i think i undertand let me try this.

Answer (score 1):

```
int main()
{
 int charsThisLine =0;
 for (int currentChar=0; currentChar<128; currentChar++)
 {
  if(charsThisLine==16)
  {
   cout<<endl;
   charsThisLine = 0;
  }
  else
  {
   cout<<(char)currentChar;
   charsThisLine++;
  }
 }
}
```